# express js route with optional parameters :different path always points to same function

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I've two routes in my express js app

```
1.router.route('/art/:category/:fieldName/:tag/:count(\\d+)?/:perPage(\\d+)?')

2.router.route('/art/search/:keyword/:count(\\d+)?/:perPage(\\d+)?')
```

when i access the second route like(`art/search/fu/1/1`) its always point to route-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your route file place route2 before route 1, 
since you manage `/art/:category` before `/art/search` express assume that `search` is a category. That's why it point to route 1 and not route 2.